# Problem when filling out a PDF and printing the PDF

Tags: vb.net, itext

I use my application to fill and print out forms.

When the form is printed out all the text except the name of the customer is stretch black...

I have tried to print the saved PDF and the same result is happening.

When i open the filled out pdf and change the text, the file is printed out correctly..

The code i'm using to fill out the PDF and printing it is under... Is there something that i can change in my code so this dont happens?

```vb
  Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    Me.xmltopdf()
    Me.Print()
End Sub

Private Sub xmltopdf()
    Dim pdfTemp As String = My.Settings.SavePDFT ' ---> It's the original pdf form you want to fill
    Dim newFile As String = My.Settings.SavePDFS & Me.TextBox1.Text & ".PDF" ' ---> It will generate new pdf that you have filled from your program

    ' ------ READING -------

    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemp)

    ' ------ WRITING -------

    ' If you don’t specify version and append flag (last 2 params) in below line then you may receive “Extended Features” error when you open generated PDF
    Dim pdfStamper As New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create), "\6c", True)

    Dim pdfFormFields As AcroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields

    ' ------ SET YOUR FORM FIELDS ------

    pdfFormFields.SetField("Field_1", TextBox1.Text)
    pdfFormFields.SetField("Field_2", TextBox2.Text)
    ' There is more fields.. just removed them this.




    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = False

    ' close the pdf
    pdfStamper.Close()
    ' pdfReader.close() ---> DON"T EVER CLOSE READER IF YOU'RE GENERATING LOTS OF PDF FILES IN LOOP
End Sub


' Print PDF
 Private Sub Print()
' Wait a bit so the PDF file is created before printing.
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500)

    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo

    psi.UseShellExecute = True

    psi.Verb = "print"

    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    'psi.Arguments = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()

    psi.FileName = My.Settings.SavePDFS & Me.Ordre_NummerTextBox.Text & ".PDF" ' Here specify a document to be printed

    Process.Start(psi)

End Sub
```

[image]

This is the printet out PDF.

Comment: This did not work after all - 

I made the Fonts and Font size the same in my application and in my PDF form, seems to work, some time not everything is printed out.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: I will try with a new PDF file, i see that my new PDF is only 140 KB when my old one was 25 MB... if it dont work i will share the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new PDF File and have had no problems with it sinse.

The old  PDF file was 25.8 MB large and the new one is only 140 kB.

Also i remember that the Old file is copied and change several times in the past.